Symmetry in correlation function with the Lindblad equation
I'm reading this paper https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.46.2668 "Laser cooling of trapped ions in a standing wave".
In the appendix, they implicitly use a formula $$\langle F(0)F(t) \rangle_{SS} = \langle F(t) F(0) \rangle_{SS}^*$$ where $\langle \cdot \rangle_{SS}$ is the expectation value with the stationary state density matrix of a Lindblad operator (assuming that $F$ is Hermite).
While it is obvious that an isolated system follows this formula, it is not clear that the system with the Lindblad equation follows this. Is there a proof for the above formula?
PS. I found a formula in Gardiner's textbook "Quantum Noise" (Eq. 5.2.6). Starting from this, and using the definition of the conjugate operator, I can prove that $$\langle A(t+\tau) B(t) \rangle = \langle B^{\dagger}(t) A^{\dagger}(t+\tau) \rangle^*.$$ For $A=B=F$, we obtain the above result.

For any mixed state quantum mechanical system (such as one governed by a Lindblad equation), the expectations value obeys the property
\begin{equation}
\langle A \rangle^* = Tr[ A \rho]^*= Tr[\rho^\dagger A^\dagger] = \langle A^\dagger \rangle.
\end{equation}
If $A = F(0)F(t)$ is a product of operators, we have to be careful with their order after conjugation:
\begin{equation}
A^\dagger = (F(0)F(t))^\dagger = F^\dagger(t)F^\dagger(0).
\end{equation}
The equality you mention
\begin{equation}
\langle F(0)F(t) \rangle_{SS} = \langle F(t) F(0) \rangle_{SS}^*
\end{equation}
is therefore satisfied if F is a Hermitian operator, that is, an observable:
\begin{equation}
 F^\dagger = F.
\end{equation}
